# EzCast | How to cast to a projector by connecting to it's Wi-Fi Hotspot and still keep internet Wi-Fi connection?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, miracast, screen-mirroring

Two days ago, my dad brought a projector that has a weird miracast system that works when something connects to **it's** wifi network and mirrors the screen using an app called EzCast.

The thing is, I want to use it to stream videos on my phone while mirroring my screen. The projector does not connect to normal wifi networks, but instead, it hosts its own network where the device to be mirrored/ cast from is to be connected to.
So If I have to watch something on the projector, I lost my internet connection.

- Is it possible to connect to two wifi networks at the same time? Or
- Is there any other way to get the desired result?. (stream videos
  online to the projector).

Thanks. Please pardon the messy wording. I'm typing this on my phone and am an ESL speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works only if the projector is **Wi-Fi Direct™**
certified, and also if your android device support such capabilities.

Wi-Fi Direct is a Wi-Fi standard enabling devices to easily connect with each other without requiring a wireless access point. Simultaneous Wi-Fi direct and network Wi-Fi is an optional feature for devices. Some devices allow this and some do not.

References

- [Can a device simultaneously connect to a regular Wi-Fi network and a group of Wi-Fi Direct-certified devices at the same time?](http://www.wi-fi.org/knowledge-center/faq/can-a-device-simultaneously-connect-to-a-regular-wi-fi-network-and-a-group-of)
- [Android running Wifi Lan and Wifi Direct simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253836/android-running-wifi-lan-and-wifi-direct-simultaneously)
- [Wi-Fi Direct](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct)